# Licensing doubts

Tags: java, licensing

I am quite new to programming and I am now creating my own program as part of my Master Thesis. My program is done in Java and uses several third-party libraries. These libraries come with different licenses, mainly:

- LGPL 2.1
- GPL 2 + GPL Linking exception
- Apache version 2
- BSD

I have actually not touched the source code of these libraries, but use them in my program and in some cases create classes that extend classes in those libraries.
 If I decide to make my program publicly available (probably for free) what kind of licence could I use? I have read much about license compatibility (Apache vs GPL vs whatever), derivative works discussions and I am very confused. Comments and explanations would be very helpful.

Comment: Which of the specific things that you have read do you doubt?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**You are free to choose any licence you like**

Here is why:

- Apache & BSD — these are permissive, they don't impose any limitations;
- LGPL 2.1 — only imposes licensing limitation on distribution of changes to the library itself;
- GPL 2 + GPL Linking exception — this is the tricky one. Basically GPL would mean that you have to release whole thing as GPL. However, since it has **linking exception**, and you do not reuse any part of source code in your source code, your code is exempt from GPL. To clarify, creating a class which extends a class imported from library is not including it's **source** code in your code, it's only linking to library and using it.

The significant part of the exception:

> As a special exception, the copyright holders of this library give you
>   permission to link this library with independent modules to produce an
>   executable, **regardless of the license terms of these independent
>   modules, and to copy and distribute the resulting executable under
>   terms of your choice**, provided that you also meet, for each linked
>   independent module, the terms and conditions of the license of that
>   module

Comment: As I do not have formal informatic schooling ( I studied biology and I am now mixing) I have no idea if using a library in Java is static linking (which appearently would force me into GPL) or if it is dynamic linking (which is a bit more contentious). According to your extract so long as I make the libraries available as I use them I should be fine no?

Comment: @Antonio: it doesn't matter if it's static or dynamic,   it's just linking, thus "linking exception" applies. The important part is that you are not modifying the library's source by extending it's classes in your source.

Comment: +1 Any explanation of the differences between GPL 2 and GPL 3? I know they tried to close some sort of "breach", but my mind always takes a nap when reading legalese :P

Comment: AFAIK, main reason behind GPLv3 was to close "tivoization" and SaaS "loopholes". BTW. it's interesting how FSF adapts more and more the language of RIAA and MPAA...

Comment: @vartec Wouldn't extending a library class count as linking to the library, rather than modifying it? Is it a grey area?

Comment: @Baqueta: hmm.. I guess I didn't make that clear enough in my answer. It is just linking.

Comment: @vartec Thought your actual answer was pretty clear, but then your first comment muddied the water: "The important part is that you are not modifying the library's source by extending it's classes in your source." :)

Comment: @Baqueta: right, it's not phrased very clear, what I meant is: extending library's classes in your source **is not** modifying that library.

Answer (score 2):

*Informal* summary:

- *GPL*: many pages stating all the things that are not allowed to do with it (who said freedom?). Basically, anything using it must become GPL or re-implement things
- *LGPL*: GPL with a little bit of flexibility: your free software can be binary linked to under certain circumstances.
- *Apache*: lots of lawyer mumbo jumbo, but a permissive License nonetheless. Requires derivative works to provide notification of any licensed or proprietary code in a common location.
- *BSD*: sweet and small license: do whatever you want with it

If you use GPL stuff, you basically have to release it under GPL as well. It is the most restrictive license of them all.

If I am not mistaken, BSD, Apache, LGPL can all be used by GPL software but not vice versa. You cannot release something under BSD using GPL code.

Edit:

correction: Apache version 2 is only compatible with GPL v3 but not GPL v2. No idea how it is affected from that linking exception.

Sources:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FSF_approved_software_licenses
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPL#Compatibility_and_multi-licensing
```

Welcome to the crazy world of licensing and the restrictiveness of GPL! ...I think everyone is lost in all these licenses and clauses anyway.

Comment: My understanding of LGPL is that you can use it in non-(L)GPL-licensed software, if you're just calling it and haven't made modifications. Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Lesser_General_Public_License#Differences_from_the_GPL  I believe the GPL2 + GPL Linking Exception is similar (though I've never looked into that one personally).

Comment: Yeah, LPGL is a lot more flexible than GPL

Comment: Thank you for the comments. As arnaud says this world of licenses is kind of crazy. Just trying to read the damn thing gives me a headache but I suppose with the other crazyness of patents it is a necessary evil.

Comment: (No downvote, this is a matter of opinion :) ) I disagree with your implication that the alleged "restrictiveness" of the GPL runs counter to "freedom". Its provisions are needed to _enforce_ freedom for everyone else, not just you. So instead of "most restrictive" I would call it the "most freedom enforcing". The problem here is that people don't usually want their software to be free (as in speech), and so they find fault in the GPL, and therefore choose a less _freedom-enforcing_ license.

Comment: @Andres: freedom as in Borg, "resistance is futile, you will be assimilated" :-P

Comment: btw. problems like that is exactly why so many companies do not want to touch anything GPL.

Comment: @vartec I know you're joking, but think about which alleged "freedom" the GPL is taking away from you: the freedom to deny others free use of the software. So it's not actually Borg-like :)

Comment: @vartec I don't find a contradiction in that. Most companies don't want to release Free software. The GPL enforces Free software. Where is the contradiction? Who is "restrictive" in this situation? ;) It makes sense that if your software is a protected, non-free asset, that you shouldn't use freedom-enforcing licenses. I'm not being a zealot here: there is a perfectly good case for using non-free licenses.

Comment: I am personally not against GPL, I would not mind being 'forced' to license my code as GPL if I use GPL code. It was my choice to use that code, I could have tried other alternatives or write it out myself. But the lawyer language in which these text are written and the diversity of different licenses out there makes it hard to know what is the 'good' (as in without breaking license) thing to do.

Comment: The main problem is that all other free software (under different licenses) cannot use GPL code. GPL is like a one way trap, it can everyone else's code but others are not allowed to use GPL code.

Comment: @Andres: the freedom that is taken away with GPL, is the freedom to decide on which license to release code, which you have written **yourself**. Also, why is it like Borg? Because if you mix Apache, MIT, BSD and whatever else Open Source with GPL, you have to release whole thing as GPL. Given how well Open Source does, I don't really think forcing people to do anything is the way to go. But of course that's more philosophical and ethical question, rather than legal.

Comment: @vartec But nobody is forcing you. You always have the freedom to choose a less free license; you just can't use GPL'ed software in that case (though there exceptions, as you noted). When you mix other licenses (such as BSD) with GPL, you have to pick the most encompassing set of rights, which is the GPL's. Choosing less would enforce less rights, which violates the GPL. Choosing _more_ doesn't harm the BSD, since said license is not concerned about additional rights. I would pick the GPL when freedom matters; and pick something else when trade secrets / proprietary software matter.

Comment: @Andres: well actually I would choose any permissive Open Source license when freedom matters, and GPL when I'd want to release something just to prevent competition from making money with alternative solution. Philosophically GPL assumes that developers are the enemy, and that they are a-holes who have to be forced to do the right thing, while permissive licenses assume that developers will gladly contribute if they want to, and that you cannot really force anyone to contribute. Now, this very similar to DRM argument, funny thing being that FSF hates DRM, yet they make same assumptions of ppl

Comment: @vartec I strongly disagree. Indeed, the GPL is _user-centric_ (whereas DRM is _publisher_-centric: it denies user rights in exchange for protecting the rights of the publisher). Developers are a kind of user in this context, so it's wrong to claim the GPL "assumes they are the enemy". The permissive licenses you prefer are _less strict_ when enforcing user freedoms, hence the name "permissive". It's ok to prefer less freedom in software, but in that case you have to give GPL'ed **free** software a miss.

Comment: @arnaud Indeed, using the GPL means "escalating" user rights. Once you escalate them, you cannot go back. I don't think it's a trap, in the sense that no implication is hidden, and the "rules of the game" won't change on you stealthily.

Comment: @Andres: ...well ...for me it implies I cannot use their code, nor can firefox developers, nor can BSD developers, nor can apache developers, nor all the others working on free open source apps which have a "do whatever you want to do with it" type of license

Comment: @arnaud Yes. I accept that enforced freedom has consequences: one consequence is that you can't restrict _other users'_ freedoms. I wouldn't use the GPL in all cases (where I work, I can't use it at all. We write proprietary software for internal use). Apache, Mozilla, et al, had their reasons for choosing a permissive license. Unfortunately, this means they cannot use software released with a freedom-enforcing license! I never said it isn't _complicated_ ;)

Comment: @Andres: this "permissive license is less freedom" argument sounds too much like *"war is peace, freedom is slavery"* from *Nineteen Eighty-Four*. Also as for user rights - access to source code is completely irrelevant for end user. It's only relevant for developers. You say that DRM *"denies user rights in exchange for protecting the rights of the publisher"*, similarly GPL denies developer rights in exchange for protecting the rights of the publisher. So the parallel is very strong.

Comment: @vartec But developers _are end users_ in this context. Think about who would be the "publisher" benefiting from the GPL in your scenario. It can't be the person who released the original GPL'ed code, since that person _already has every right_. The "publisher" in this context is whoever redistributes GPL'ed software. What probably bothers you is the GPL's most important provision: that you (the publisher) cannot deny rights to any other user. By using GPL code in your own, and redistributing your program, you accept you cannot deny these rights from other users.

Comment: BTW, if this sounds political, it's because it is. Read the FSF website or any of Stallman's speeches: the issue is _political_, not technical (as opposed to the OSI, which claim to be merely technical).

Comment: @Andres: *"GPL's most important provision: that you (the publisher) cannot deny rights to any other user"* we can go on with this ad infinitum, but let me reiterate. I feel that releasing something with GPL instead of BSD, you **are denying** user, (as in developer), the right to choose with what software combine your work. It's also wrong to think that someone may "close" the BSD project. Someone my choose not to share **his** contribution, but that's not net loss to original project. And GNU ObjC fiasco is best example how GPL really can't force anyone into making **valuable** contribution.

Comment: @vartec Again, I disagree. First, let's agree we are discussing _distribution_ of derivatives of Free Software (if you're not distributing anything in any sense, the GPL doesn't kick in). If you _are_ distributing, and you attempt to close the derivative, it IS a loss to the original project. How big this loss is depends on the project. You benefited from the project but won't allow others to benefit from your derivative in the same way, thus denying their rights. Let me stress that _it's entirely ok to do so_, just not with GPL'ed software.

Comment: @vartec Also, you are not denying the user anything. The developer _chose_ a tool (in this case, Free software), and must then abide by its rules. The rules are sensible for their purpose: to guarantee freedom of use and modification. _It's ok to choose other licenses which make fewer guarantees about freedom_ (i.e. more "permissive"), you just have to understand the trade-offs!

Comment: Interesting debate, but lets please take this to chat if you feel this needs to be discussed further.

Comment: While what you say is true, he's not asking about the GPL but about the "GPL 2 + GPL Linking exception".